# get only text from element

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

I have this :

```
var y = $(document.getElementById('{{ forloop.counter }}')).text();
console.log(y)
```

In my console i have this :

```
My text1

          var y = $(document.getElementById('1')).text();
          console.log(y)
My text2

          var y = $(document.getElementById('2')).text();
          console.log(y)
```

How can i get just `My text`, without funcs.
Tried `.textContext` but console shows that the element `undefined`

UPD

```
<div class="span4 collapse-group">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#">Check &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse">
      <div class="card card-body">
        {{text}}
        <script>
        $(".card").each(function(i,e){
  var text = $(e).text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: did you try with only Jquery: `$('#1').text()`?

Comment: yeah, only jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your loop is:

```
{% for item in list %}
<div id="item_{{forloop.counter}}" class="item_list">{{ item.text }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

In js you could target the unique class `item_list` an iterate through them with `each()`:

```
$(".item_list").each(function(i,e){
    var text = $(e).text();
    if(!text || text == undefined){
       console.log('empty');
    }
    # //further processes
});
```

Comment: yeah my loops like you described, i`ve updated my body question added code, deleted {{forloop.counter}}, but still in console recieve my text+code of  func . i dont need a code

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what the console displays in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You you are trying to get text of element is wrong. You can either do `$('#2').text()` or  `document.getElementById('1').textContent`

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

The `textContent` property sets or returns the text content of the specified node, and all its descendants.

```js
var y = $('#1').text();
          console.log(y)

 var y = $('#2').text();
          console.log(y)
          
  var y = document.getElementById('1').textContent;
  
   console.log(y)
   
   var y = document.getElementById('2').textContent;
  
   console.log(y)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">Div 1</div>
<div id="2">Div 2</div>
```

Comment: but i have loops, my elements are dynamic. I want to get to them to check them if they are empty, and after that i want to hide some buttons

Comment: so @ZhaZha , in that case, give them a unique class, and use `each()` for your validations